# How to data bind a ListView item to an item in a structured list with multiple indexes?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to data bind a list of information to a `ListView` in `Xamarin.forms`, but I'm having issues because of how it is indexed. I need to get the string of information found in `sortedList[0].Info[multiple indexes].CoverLink` to display on my Image element inside of my `Xamarin` app, but I'm not sure how to go about it. My `Xaml` file is as follows:

```
<ListView RowHeight="100" x:Name="PinnedListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                            <Image Source="{Binding CoverLink}" HeightRequest="100"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding SomeOtherBinding}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

and I'm assigning the ItemSource via `c#` by stating:

```
PinnedListView.ItemsSource = sortedList;
```

Here is a screenshot of my list architecture:

[image]

How to data bind it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the `CoverLink` is in the `Info`nested array, so, in order to access to it try this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Info[0].CoverLink}" HeightRequest="100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify which element of the Info array you want to use

```
<Image Source="{Binding Info[0].CoverLink}" HeightRequest="100"/>
```

Comment: That will only populate the list with the first index of the info array. I need it to populate with all of the indexes.

Comment: how do you plan to populate a single Image control with multiple images?  If you want to display an image control for each image you'll probably need to write a custom control.

Comment: I don’t... look up what data binding does to a ListView with a DataTemplate.